# How does Solid Fog work with flying creatures?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, flight

> ...the solid fog is so thick that any creature attempting to move through it progresses at a speed of 5 feet...

So that a flying creature would have to reduce its flying speed to 5 feet when it is in a solid fog.

And if the flying creature does not have better-than-average maneuverability, then it will fall.

> If a flying creature fails to maintain its minimum forward speed, it must land at the end of its movement. If it is too high above the ground to land, it falls straight down, descending 150 feet in the first round of falling.

Interestingly, it seems solid fog does not stop a creature from dropping or limit its dropping speed to 5 feet. Instead, it says:

> A creature or object that falls into solid fog is slowed, so that each 10 feet of vapor that it passes through reduces falling damage by 1d6.

(If it simply reduces the speed to 5 feet, then there won't be any falling damage. As a comparison, Featherfall reduces the falling speed to 60 feet which has no falling damage.)

So I assume that if a flying creature is trapped in a Solid Fog, it will trigger falling rule since 5 feet is less than its minimum forward speed, and hence instantly leave the Solid Fog area and either take falling damage or can start flying again from next round.

Is this the correct way to read these rules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, as written.

Doesn’t make a great deal of sense to me, and I would be inclined to houserule it if it ever came up, but that is what they wrote. It’s never come up for me so I don’t have any tried or tested houserule for it.

Comment: When a creature's speed gets reduced, shouldn't "half of its speed" requirement also be reduced?

Comment: @annoyingimp Oh, that’s an impossible question. I guess it could be!

Comment: @annoyingimp I wonder if that "half of its speed" means its original speed or the current speed. Like, can a dragon avoid falling if it is under the effect of *Haste* but is flying at half of its original flying speed?

Comment: @annoyingimp No, it would still be this question.

Comment: This would be an interesting question for World Building or Physics - if the solid fog makes the air thick enough to slow movement by X amount, how does that change the speed required to stay aloft?

Comment: @KRyan Will you expand your answer to include this topic than?

Comment: @DavidK It should be, probably. The higher the gas density, the less speed an object would require to stay aloft.